# An efficent way to stop a sepcific website from making POST requests to your server?

Tags: curl, post, http-headers

I have a server and I want to ban some specific websites from making POST requests. I know I can check the referrer but it can be easily changed by making the request using cURL with fake headers. I am looking for something which cannot be easiliy faked using headers. I wanna stop spamming from these websites

Comment: what webserver?

Comment: Apache webserver edit:  no sorry it's nginx

Comment: Use CAPTCHA and/or CSRF tokens.

Comment: personally id use the firewall to do this... and not handle this in software

Comment: @AlexHowansky Captchas aren't an option as I need to use an application to make automatic post requests

Comment: Have you tried CORS?

Comment: @JakeaHacks make a second endpoint secured differently for that

Comment: Just whitelist the (likely one) IP that your requests are coming from.

Comment: @AnthonyJClink No actually it's the same part of the server which needs to be used both by the application and at the same time not usable by the website

Comment: @AlexHowansky Can't you fake IPs with cURL?

Comment: Is the POST request made clientside (i.e. by visitors of that site), or serverside?

Comment: _"Can't you fake IPs with cURL?"_ No.

Comment: @CodeCaster Serverside

Comment: Thanks for answers. I will try ;)

Answer (score 0):

If the traffic is specific to an ip or ip group I would use the access controls important to your server type. For nginx:

```
vi nginx.conf

deny IP;
deny subnet;
allow IP;
allow subnet;
# block all ips
deny 1.2.3.4;
deny 91.212.45.0/24;
deny 91.212.65.0/24;
# allow all ips 
allow    all;
```

see this post for more specific details.https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-nginx-access-control-howto/

Comment: I made a mistake. It's nginx/1.11.10

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

You explained in comments that this is a serverside post, so you can simply add some form of authentication to this part of  your site.

The most trivial way would be to hand out API tokens to sites you do want to let post to your site. They then supply this token with each request (either in the query string or as a request header), which you then validate.